# Pause transition and restart after async call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to check if user is logged each time the state I transition to or it's parent has some isLogged data attribute. My code is:

```
        service.watchHasAccess = function(){
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event,toState,toStateParams){
            if(typeof toState.data !=='undefined' && typeof toState.data.loggedIn !== 'undefined' && toState.data.loggedIn == true){
                api.getWithPromise('user/isLoggedIn').then(function(response){
                    if(response.status !=='OK'){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        FlashMessage.showError('Zaloguj się aby przejść tutaj.');
                        $state.go('MainPage');                            
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The problem is that when transitioning to restricted state it does load, but it almost immediately redirects to MainPage state. It is like flash. It is because I use async request so I assume that state just transition no matter what result of request, but then response comes and I am transitioned properly. What I would like to achieve is to wait until promise get resolved then check and eventually redirect user to 'MainPage'. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use promises for your asyc and resolve or reject the promise based on what is returned.  I would suggest that the URL switching would take place in the `$stateChangeError` event listener, which would be fired by rejection of the promise.  You can pass the location you want to go to in the `reject([data])` to the listener.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/L9jxf/2/

Some promise that will reject after a timeout (simulates server call)

```
        protected: ['$timeout', '$q', function ($timeout, $q) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.reject({type:'redirect',location:'401'});
            }, 1000);
            return deferred.promise;
        }]
```

This handles the rejection

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (e, to, toParams, from, fromParams, error) {
        if (error.type === 'redirect') {
            $state.transitionTo(error.location);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I managed to do this, but I have one more question. I put this resolve in my 'user' state so if I would go to 'user.stuff' the resolve would be checked again. The problem is that this resolve is proccesed once when going to 'user.anything' state and then when I go to 'user.anything2' it is not  resolved again. I kinda understand why this happens, but the question is if there is some better solution than putting $state.reload() on top of every controller that is used inside of 'user' state. Hopefully you understand my question :)

Comment: I think I understand.  You have multiple states nested within a `user` state. You want the `user` state to resolve each time any state within it is accessed.  I don't think this is possible. When navigating within siblings, the parent state is never reloaded and thus never re-resolved. Besides `$state.reload()` you can put the resolve on every state that would need it.

Comment: I think it is kind of overkill to do so, I used [code]$state.reload()[/code] since I know this controller will always need to be used when logged in. Anyway thanks for the answer :)